# Using step function as activation function in the final layer

Tags: deep-learning, image-processing, backpropagation, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I am using variational autoencoders as machine learning algorithm. My input data are images/matrices that represent  user interface layouts or how the HTML page will be divided. I am thinking to implement step function as an activation function in the final layer of my model. However, according to the documentation that I read, back-propagation requires differentiable activation function.
The derivative of step function is 0.

My question is whether it is a good idea to use step or staircase as activation in the final layer (in the decoder) ?

If I do, will it effect the weights of the other previous layers ?

The motivation behind using step function as activation function is the fact that I want to discretize my output data.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, it's unusual to use a step function as an activation because it's non-differentiable. I believe it's possible to train this type of network anyway simply by telling your autodiff implementation that the gradient of the step function is the gradient of the sigmoid activation (even though that is not mathematically correct).

If you want to discretize your network outputs, why not interpret the output as bernoulli variables and sample to discretize?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried some post-processing transformations as sampling, filtering and discretization. But those as I said, are post processing, they are not included in the machine learning model. So, can you please give me a link or a hint how to interpret the output as bernoulli variables because I didn't see that previously.

Comment: I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow so helpful !!